# Charge only shipping as a repair cost after an order

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

There are possible instances when a customer has a product, and will need to send it back to be repaired or some modifications. 
I want to add shipping at customer's expense again.
How can I charge a customer for the $5.99 shipping without them ordering a product again as it is a repair for the same ordered product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to avoid invoicing the customer until you were sure that all charges related to the issue were complete. However, this is not ideal, as typically one would want to wait to ship a product until the funds were captured after invoicing.

In this case, I'd suggest creating a virtual product that is only visible to CSRs. The CSR can then add it to a new order when the customer notifies them that they need a repair, and then place and invoice the order, enabling you to charge them the shipping.

In short, there aren't really ways to do this in Magento without ordering more products, but if you are willing to create a new order, it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was also trying in a way by editing the order and adding custom price just to add my desired charge but the issue I faced there is, editing the order when ordered using credit card doesn't shows me the previous ordered product but not incase ordered using credit/money order.
Any idea!

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal Nope not familiar with that. Editing an order cancels the old one, and I don't think you want that here... Make sense? It should show the old items on the order though...

Comment: I agree that. Do share something in favour if you have in future. Need to know this!

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal thanks, will do. Would you be willing to upvote and accept?